# How do I pipe multiple non-exiting commands together in bash?

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I'm trying to do `tail -f /tmp/myfile | grep abcde | python extract.py`, where `extract.py` reads one line from stdin, using `sys.stdin.readline()`. The first two commands piped together results in the expected output and the program waiting for more input, but when I pipe this into my python program, it hangs on the `sys.stdin.readline()` command.

Contents of `extract.py`:

```
import sys

line = sys.stdin.readline()
print(line)
```

While the command is running, doing `echo "abcde" >> /tmp/myfile` produces no output.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Which line are you trying to read? The first new line in myfile that contains abcde? The first existing line in myfile that matches?

Comment: Try `grep --line-buffered ... | python -u ...` to unbuffer everything.

Comment: Watch those truncating writes, though. My `tail` catches them and notifies me there was a truncation, but it might cause some issues in some cases. Use `>>` instead of `>` to append.